# ¿Cómo puedo añadir una palabra al principio de cada línea en un texto?

Tags: python

Me gustaría saber si alguien podría resolverme esta duda:

Teniendo un texto (texto1.txt) con varias líneas escritas:

```
buenos días
qué tal
cómo estás
```

¿Cómo podría añadir con python la palabra *hola* al principio de cada una de estas líneas? De manera que el output fuese:

```
hola buenos días
hola qué tal estás
hola cómo estás
```

¡Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: que has intentado?

Comment: Deberias leer un poco acerca de la  manipulación de cadenas: https://programminghistorian.org/es/lecciones/manipular-cadenas-de-caracteres-en-python

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda ;) Tenía que haber dejado el código que estaba utilizando para haber sido algo más preciso en mi pregunta. Para la próxima, ya lo sé :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues el código en python sería algo así:

```
#python 2.7
file=open("texto1.txt","r")
lineas=file.readlines()
for linea in lineas:
    print "Hola" + linea
file.close()
```

PS: Como no especificas la version de Python, es posible que tengas que hacer algunos cambios mínimos. 
Espero ayudarte

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, YORS. Muy amable ;)

Answer (score 0):

¡Perfecto! Es justo lo que estaba intentando hacer, pero no lo conseguía. 
Estoy utilizando la última versión de python y, añadiendo () en el print, sale.

Me estaba volviendo loco y ya me estaba yendo a otras cosas que no tenían nada que ver, y era mucho más sencillo de lo que pensaba.

Lo último que había probado era esto:

```
texto = input('Introduce el texto que quieras: ')
file_salida = open(texto, encoding='utf-8')
t = list()
for palabra in file_salida:
    t.append(('Hola ' + palabra))

print (t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Vi lo que has hecho y veo que no has puesto el `'r'`cuando lees el documento de texto, te recomiendo que lo coloques para saber cuando lees un documento. Además, lo puse un poco más compacto en la parte del **for**.

```
texto = input('Introduce el texto que quieras: ')
file_salida = open(texto, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
t = ['Hola ' + palabra for palabra in file_salida]
print (t)
```

#### Resultado

```
>> Introduce el texto que quieras: texto1.txt
>> ['Hola señor\n', 'Hola buen dia']
```

Espero haberte ayudado :)